Adafruit fingerprint sensor library error on a Raspberry Pi 4
I'm trying to test my fingerprint sensor, it shows up on the terminal too, but when I run this code this error shows up:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'adafruit_fingerprint' has no attribute 'Adafruit_Fingerprint'

And the library has already been installed using pip, I checked the adafruit official code also does not work, same error.
The code:
import time
import serial
import adafruit_fingerprint

# Open serial port
uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

# Initialize fingerprint sensor
finger = adafruit_fingerprint.Adafruit_Fingerprint(uart)

def get_fingerprint():
    """Get a finger print image, template it, and see if it matches!"""
    print("Waiting for image...")
    while finger.get_image() != adafruit_fingerprint.OK:
        pass
    print("Templating...")
    if finger.image_2_tz(1) != adafruit_fingerprint.OK:
        return False
    print("Searching...")
    if finger.finger_search() != adafruit_fingerprint.OK:
        return False
    return True

# Test the function
while True:
    if get_fingerprint():
        print("Fingerprint found!")
    else:
        print("Fingerprint not found.")
    time.sleep(1)



Expected the code to work.

You're missing the import for the library.  Where were you expecting the name adafruit_fingerprint to come from?  It's certainly not built into Python...

i added it, but then this error shows up:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 9, in <module> AttributeError: module 'adafruit_fingerprint' has no attribute 'Adafruit_Fingerprint'

A quick look at the documentation shows that the class is named AdafruitFingerprint, without an underscore.

A quick look at the documentation shows that the class is named AdafruitFingerprint, without an underscore
